# JavaScript (ES6): Named parameters and default values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am coming from Python and am really liking the way to set named parameters and default values—now it seems that [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) allows me to do similar. But I can't see why this last call breaks:

```
fun = ({first=1, last=1}) => (1*first+2*last)

console.log("-----------")

console.log( fun({first:1, last:2}) )

console.log("-----------")

console.log( fun({last:1, first:2}) )

console.log("-----------")

console.log( fun() ) // Breaks
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't have *named arguments*. Object deconstruction is not the same, even if it can be used to implement something close to named arguments. You shouldn't approach them the same way.

Comment: it's because you are thinking of them as kwargs. It's not the same. Good answers below.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need a default object.

```js
var fun = ({ first = 1, last = 1 } = {}) => 1 * first + 2 * last;
//                                 ^^^^

console.log(fun({ first: 1, last: 2 }));
console.log(fun({ last: 1, first: 2 }));
console.log(fun());
```

Answer (score 3):

Cause you need an object which can be deconstructed:

```
fun({})
```

Comment: Like this answer because it forces me to remember that I always must pass an object